# RAPIDS pip installation issue

Tags: python, docker, pip, rapids

I've been trying to install RAPIDS in my Docker environment, which initially went smoothly. However, over the past one or two weeks, I've been encountering an error.

The issue seems to be that pip is attempting to fetch from the default PyPi registry, where it encounters a placeholder project. I'm unsure who placed it there or why, as it appears to serve no practical purpose.

````bash
 => ERROR [12/19] RUN pip3 install cudf-cu11 cuml-cu11 cugraph-cu11 cucim --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com                                             2.1s 
------                                                                                                                                                               
 > [12/19] RUN pip3 install cudf-cu11 cuml-cu11 cugraph-cu11 cucim --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com:                                                        
#0 1.038 Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.nvidia.com                                                                                        
#0 1.466 Collecting cudf-cu11                                                                                                                                        
#0 1.542   Downloading cudf-cu11-23.6.0.tar.gz (6.8 kB)                                                                                                              
#0 1.567   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#0 1.972   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#0 1.980   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 1.980   
#0 1.980   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#0 1.980   │ exit code: 1
#0 1.980   ╰─> [16 lines of output]
#0 1.980       Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 1.980         File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
#0 1.980         File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
#0 1.980         File "/tmp/pip-install-8463q674/cudf-cu11_9d3e1a792dae4026962cdff29926ce8d/setup.py", line 137, in <module>
#0 1.980           raise RuntimeError(open("ERROR.txt", "r").read())
#0 1.980       RuntimeError:
#0 1.980       ###########################################################################################
#0 1.980       The package you are trying to install is only a placeholder project on PyPI.org repository.
#0 1.980       This package is hosted on NVIDIA Python Package Index.
#0 1.980       
#0 1.980       This package can be installed as:
#0 1.980       ```
#0 1.980       $ pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi.nvidia.com cudf-cu11
#0 1.980       ```
#0 1.980       ###########################################################################################
#0 1.980       
#0 1.980       [end of output]
#0 1.980   
#0 1.980   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 1.983 error: metadata-generation-failed
#0 1.983 
#0 1.983 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
#0 1.983 ╰─> See above for output.
#0 1.983 
#0 1.983 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#0 1.983 hint: See above for details.
````

I attempted to explicitly set the `--index-url` to `pypi.nvidia.com`, but this approach wasn't feasible either, as the dependencies for the RAPIDS packages appear to be hosted on the default PyPi.

Comment: the recommendation to use `--extra-index-url` looks wrong. Tehre is no priority between the default (pypi) index and the extra index. `pip` will use the first package it finds with that name, which happens to be the "placeholder" on pypi. Try installing with `--index-url` instead (and maybe report this to NVIDIA devs)

Comment: As stated, I tried the `--index-url` option already but got an error when it tries to resolve the dependencies for `cudf` as they seem to not beeing hosted on `pypi.nvidia.com`.

I'll guess search for the best place to report that to NVIDIA devs as it seems to be broken.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread. Workaround could be to install the dependencies seperately using PyPi index, then install only the nvidia packages with `--index-url pypi.nvidia.com`. Yet another alternative could be to use miniconda and install with `conda`

Comment: Can you report the Python version you are using? RAPIDS 23.06 supports Python 3.9 and 3.10. At present, RAPIDS is tracking a potential issue with Python 3.8 throwing this error because the placeholder is compatible with 3.8 but the wheels on pypi.nvidia.com are not.

Comment: To clarify some conversions above, RAPIDS wheels like cudf-cu11 have some dependencies from pypi.nvidia.com and some from the main PyPI. Using the “extra” index URL is necessary for that reason. Also, the placeholder on the main PyPI is used to help direct users to the NVIDIA PyPI server — RAPIDS cannot use the main PyPI due to the size of the RAPIDS packages and some other more minor reasons.

Comment: I'm indeed using python3.8 out of a docker container running ros2-foxy. We are currently investigating if we can upgrade to humble which would then be bundled within a ubuntu22.04 container with python3.10. But for the moment I read the issue in cudf and hope that version 23.04 of RAPIDS will temporarily work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has already been reported in the cudf repository and it seems to have existed since version 23.06.

I will try the suggested workaround of installing version 23.04 and will report back if this temporarily resolves the problem.

### Original Issue:

https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/13642

### Feedback:

Using strict versioning to 23.04 worked perfectly.
I simply replaced the unversioned pip install with a versioned one:

```bash
# Before
pip3 install cudf-cu11 cuml-cu11 cugraph-cu11 cucim --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com

# After
pip3 install cudf-cu11==23.04 cuml-cu11==23.04 cugraph-cu11==23.04 cucim --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com
```

One thing to note for anyone else encountering this issue while building in an Ubuntu 20.04 container: you need to add `RUN apt remove python3-psutil` before installing rapids, to allow `pip` to install psutil in the correct version.

Comment: I still have the same problem with the versioned command

Comment: That's strange, for me the versioned command is working since June and I had no further issues since I use it.